# how to get values from the content?

Tags: php

{"prereqs":{"prereq":{"type":"prereq_check","value":"submerging_island_feature_enabled"}},"divisions":{"division":[{"items":{"item":[{"name":"rhino_shell","rarity":"common"},{"name":"walrus_wavy","rarity":"special"},{"name":"hippo_fancyshell","rarity":"rare"},{"name":"rhino_jellyfish","rarity":"superRare"}]},"name":"rubyCount_30"},{"items":{"item":[{"name":"walrus_clam","rarity":"common"},{"name":"hippo_nautical","rarity":"special"},{"name":"giraffe_coral","rarity":"rare"},{"name":"elephant_starburst","rarity":"superRare"}]},"name":"rubyCount_40"},{"items":{"item":[{"name":"giraffe_waverider","rarity":"common"},{"name":"pony_sea","rarity":"special"},{"name":"magicdeer_seadeer","rarity":"rare"},{"name":"pony_seaprincesscorn","rarity":"superRare"}]},"name":"rubyCount_50"},{"items":{"item":[{"name":"bigcat_crystallion","rarity":"common"},{"name":"magicdeer_midnightdeer","rarity":"special"},{"name":"horse_ofthesea","rarity":"rare"},{"name":"horse_wingedsea","rarity":"superRare"}]},"name":"rubyCount_60"}]},"crafting":{"recipes":{"recipe":[{"name":"qdke"},{"name":"sb1p"},{"name":"cb8v"}]}},"listEndDate":"07/13/2015","currencyItem":{"name":"healingpotionbottle"},"feed":{"throttleTime":"21600"},"name":"submerging_island"}

Comment: http://php.net/json_decode

Comment: Welcome, please read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get you going my 2 cents. First off, Welcome, please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

First you need to decode the json string in to an array. with that array you can get the values.

```
<?php

$json = '{"prereqs":{"prereq":{"type":"prereq_check","value":"submerging_island_feature_enabled"}},
"divisions":{"division":[{"items":{"item":[{"name":"rhino_shell","rarity":"common"},
{"name":"walrus_wavy","rarity":"special"},{"name":"hippo_fancyshell","rarity":"rare"},
{"name":"rhino_jellyfish","rarity":"superRare"}]},"name":"rubyCount_30"},
{"items":{"item":[{"name":"walrus_clam","rarity":"common"},{"name":"hippo_nautical","rarity":"special"},
{"name":"giraffe_coral","rarity":"rare"},{"name":"elephant_starburst","rarity":"superRare"}]},"name":"rubyCount_40"},
{"items":{"item":[{"name":"giraffe_waverider","rarity":"common"},{"name":"pony_sea","rarity":"special"},
{"name":"magicdeer_seadeer","rarity":"rare"},
{"name":"pony_seaprincesscorn","rarity":"superRare"}]},"name":"rubyCount_50"},
{"items":{"item":[{"name":"bigcat_crystallion","rarity":"common"},{"name":"magicdeer_midnightdeer","rarity":"special"},
{"name":"horse_ofthesea","rarity":"rare"},
{"name":"horse_wingedsea","rarity":"superRare"}]},"name":"rubyCount_60"}]},"crafting":{"recipes":{"recipe":[{"name":"qdke"},
{"name":"sb1p"},{"name":"cb8v"}]}},"listEndDate":"07/13/2015","currencyItem":{"name":"healingpotionbottle"},"feed":{"throttleTime":"21600"},"name":"submerging_island"}';

//decode the json
$decoded = json_decode($json, true);


// uncomment if you want it to be easier to read
// echo "<pre>";
// print_r($decoded);
// echo "</pre>";

//if you want the singe value, i.e. name of the first item.
echo "If you want a sinle value:<br>";
echo $decoded['divisions']['division'][0]['items']['item'][0]['name'] . "<br>";

//to get all names from one item  you need to use a foreach() loop. 
echo "<br>if you want all names from one item:<br>";
foreach($decoded['divisions']['division'][0]['items']['item'] AS $value){
    echo $value['name'] . "<br>";
}

//to get all names we need to use 2 foreach loops because this is nested in multiple arrays
echo "<br>if you want all names from all items:<br>";
foreach($decoded['divisions']['division'] AS $value){
    foreach($value['items']['item'] AS $value){
        echo $value['name'] . "<br>";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: @ErickAdhikari If you "accepting an answer" you click the check mark that appears next to the answer.